# How to change or replace animation while sprite is running action and animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2D and SneakyInput Joystick to make a fighting game.
I have a character and some animation for this character. (walkAnim, attackAnim, jumpAnim... etc)

I want to do something like: When I press jumpButton, the character will run ccjumpby and jumpAnim.

While character is jumping, I press attackButton to make the character run attackAnim and the character is still running ccjumpby.

Without attackbutton, the character is still run jumpAnim and ccjumpby.

All I want to do is just like "street fighter".

In character.m, I have:

```
- (void) jumpButtonPress {
    id action = nil;
    id movementAction = nil;
    CGPoint newPosition;
    newPosition = ccp(screenSize.width * 0.2f, 0.0f);
    if ([self flipX] == YES) {
        newPosition = ccp(newPosition.x * -1.0f, 0.0f);
    } 
    movementAction = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.5f 
                                       position:newPosition 
                                         height:160.0f 
                                          jumps:1];
    action = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCAnimate 
                       actionWithAnimation:crouchingAnim 
                       restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                      [CCSpawn actions:
                       [CCAnimate 
                        actionWithAnimation:jumpingAnim 
                        restoreOriginalFrame:YES],
                       movementAction,
                       nil],
                      [CCAnimate 
                       actionWithAnimation:afterJumpingAnim 
                       restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                      nil];
    [self runAction:action];
}

- (void) attackButtonPressed {
    action = [CCAnimate 
                          actionWithAnimation:rightPunchAnim 
                          restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
    [self runAction:action];
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's happening? What's not happening?

Comment: I pressed attackButton while Character jumping, but Character still running jumpingAnim.If I add [self stopAllAnimation]; in attackButtonPressed method, when I pressed attackButton, Character will cancel moventAction to run rightPunchAnim.

Comment: I've tried [Character setDisplayFrameWithAnimationName:rightPunchAnim index:0],but it show  'cannot find Animation name',and crash.